# PrimeFaces. Content-Security-Policy problem with <p:editor> tag

Tags: jsf, primefaces, content-security-policy

I am using **Primefaces 8.0** in my project.
And I'm trying to configure the Content Security Policy as described [here](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/contentsecuritypolicy).

This is what my configuration looks like:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.CSP</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.CSP_POLICY</param-name>
        <param-value>script-src 'self' https://wchat.freshchat.com</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Everything works fine in Mozilla Firefox.
But in Google Chrome I get these error messages:

```
jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:2  Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://wchat.freshchat.com 'unsafe-hashes' 'nonce-MWYzYWZiMTEtNzM0Mi00Mzc1LWI0OTMtZTY3YWU4NTI2NjIx'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I noticed that these errors occur on pages that use [PrimeFaces Editor](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-v8/ui/input/editor.xhtml)

Apparently the problem is `src="javascript:true;` which is added when PrimeFaces Editor is rendered.

[image]

Please advise how to fix this problem.

Comment: Since version 10, the "p:editor" tag has been removed. 
From migration guide 8 ->10: "Removed Editor component in favor TextEditor."
And I will not reproduce this problem. 
By the way, in version 8 there is no problem with TextEditor as with Editor.
But I need to save exactly Editor now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editor is no longer supported and was removed in PF10.  It is not able to be CSP enabled and was yet another reason to remove it.  I suggest moving to TextEditor to both allow you to upgrade and to prevent CSP issues.